# Number of words of length $l$ using $n$ characters

Tags: combinatorics

Given length of word $l$ and number of characters available $n$,
find the total number of words that can be formed using available characters of length $l$.

Example:

If $n=2$, and the available characters are $(0,1)$

When $l=2$ 
The words we can make are $\rightarrow$ $00$, $01$, $10$, $11$

When $l=3$ 
The words we can make are $\rightarrow$ $000$, $001$, $010$, $011$, $100$, $101$, $110$, $111$

Comment: i tried but not get any successful formula :( or pattern

Comment: Do you know about the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: you can think about this problem in two ways. Both lead to the same answer.

1. You have $l$ places in a word and you can independently choose one of the $n$ letters for each place.
2. Suppose you know how many words of length $l-1$. Each word of length $l$ can be constructed as a word of length $l-1$ concatenated with some letter at the end. So, for each word you have $n$ options of choosing the last letter. You get a recurrent formula $W_l = n \cdot W_{l-1}$.

I think these two patterns will help.